# ngCookies doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to create a simple cookie on my browser, but it doesn't show it on the developper tools.

The first time I do:

```
$cookies.test = "a basic value";
console.debug($cookies.test);
```

When refreshing the page, it shows on the Console tab the correct string, even if I cant't see any cookie with this value on the Resources tab. (I'm using Google Chrome)

The second time I do:

```
console.debug($cookies.test);
```

After refreshing, the Console shows `undefined`. Which seems correct, because theis no cookie stored in the browser...

Where are stored this "cookies" of Angular? Am I doing something wrong ?

**Note:** I also tried using `$cookieStore`, I have exactly the same behavior, though the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Angular `ngCookie` works just fine.
The problem comes from the project type. I had to convert my Static Web Project to a Dynamic one on Eclipse.

See: [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwpcnvrt.html)
(Personally, on Luna, I had to : right clic on my project > Configure > Convert to dynamic Project...)

To create a tomcat server to host your application, see: [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fttomcatserv.html)